# How to read a file line by line, and split each line

Tags: c++

I need to read a file line by line, and store the first word of each line in one string, and the following words on the same line in another string.

Example line: aardvark n. Mammal with a tubular snout and a long tongue, feeding on termites. [afrikaans]

I need to store the first word in a word variable, and the rest of the line in a definition variable of a dictionaryEntry class.

In java I would use string.split() or string.indexOf() but I can't figure out how I would go about doing this in C++

```
ifstream inp(filename);
while(getline(inp, line))
{
     //separate first word and rest of line
     string word=
     string rest=
     DictionaryEntry de(word, rest);
}
```

Comment: Use `>>` to get the first word and `getline` to go the rest of the line?

Comment: `std::string::find_first_not_of` should be your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifstream inp(filename);
while(getline(inp, line))
{
     //separate first word and rest of line
     string word= line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
     string rest= line.substr(line.find(" ") + 1);
     DictionaryEntry de(word, rest);
}
```

[std::string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/): Returns a portion of a string.

[std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/): Returns the position of a string or char. Returns "std::string::npos" if no results.

Answer (score 0):

As @NathanOliver suggested. This should work:

```
std::string FirstWord, line;

while(inp >> FirstWord)
{
   getline(inp, line);
   // .. your stuff
}
```